# Selenium Chrome web driver prompt for download

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium bot running on a windows server that hits a download link and stores the downloaded file to a directory specified in the chrome options. The problem I am facing here is that even after using the below options, I am getting the prompt for download every time I run the script.

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": config["download_dir"],
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": False,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": False
    })
```

I tried giving the default download directory path that windows have, but I am still getting the prompt for download.

My guess was that Comodo Antivirus was the culprit here since I started facing this issue right after installing the antivirus. But even after uninstalling the antivirus and then restoring to a Windows image before the antivirus installation, I am getting the prompt for download.

Any suggestions as to what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

can you check for necessary user permissions. also post detail error

Comment: I am not getting any errors at all. The problem is even after giving the default download directory, I am getting the prompt window for download - the one we get when we click on "Save as" as well. The download directory we are mentioning has all the permissions enabled as well.

Comment: Can you try updating your chrome version to latest one if it not or try manually in your chrome browser to make sure that the prompt is coming or not as chrome by default do not ask for a prompt dialog .Also , try to clear the cache as well of browser .

Comment: `driver.manage().deleteAllcookies();` this is java. use your language cookie handler. 
Also try to get chromedriver suitable for your chrome version.
If you are using any framework such as TestNG or Junit better to go for stable version rather than beta.